# adding segmented control with in the Navigation Bar

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol

can anybody help with the code on how to add segmented control within the navigation bar....i have seen it on some applications and want to implement it

thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do you want to use Interface Builder or do it in code only?

With IB operation is very straightforward, you only need to drag segmented control to place on navigation bar where title is located. Title will be replaced by the segmented control.

If you want to accomplish this in code, please refer to [this section of iPhone reference library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW25). It seems you need to set navigation item's `titleView` property to your segmented control, which is subclass of UIView, so this is completely legal.

Answer (score 2):

in `viewDidLoad`:

obj-c:

```
NSArray *segmentTitles = @[
    @"segment1",
    @"segment2",
];

UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segmentTitles];
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
segmentedControl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
// change the width from 400.0 to something you want if it's needed
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400.0f, 30.0f);
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl;
```

swift:

```
let segmentTitles = [
    "segment1",
    "segment2",
]

let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: segmentTitles)
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
segmentedControl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
// change the width from 400.0 to something you want if it's needed
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400.0, 30.0)
segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: "segmentChanged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl
```